# What do I do if my Xbox 360 is glitching my games and doing weird things?

Tags: xbox-360, fable-3

I was fighting Logan’s soldiers in Fable 3 and suddenly my Xbox made a screeching noise and my T.V. had clear lines running threw it in a zig zag pattern. What does that mean? I still haven’t been able to become king in Fable 3 because of my Xbox 360. When I tried playing Minecraft, I put in the disc and it shot it right out! What’s going on? Does it mean I need a new Xbox?

Comment: With the whole screeching sound, something similar happened to my Wii quite a long time ago after I left it on all night to save my progress. If you've left it on for a while, try not to do that as it doesn't do much good to the hardware.

Comment: Are there any other signs of the console or anything else being corrupt? "lines" seem to indicate a problem with wire/port connection, are they inserted correctly? Worst case scenario, system screwed up big time.

Comment: I've found [this video](https://youtu.be/Ab7xnKPxcj4?t=341) showing the situation. Can you reporduce?

Comment: I didn’t leave it on, everything is plugged in correctly, what does reproduce mean for an Xbox?

Comment: "Reproduce" means that you can relate, that you can trigger the same problem in your own circumstances. In this case in the video the last sound the xbox plays sounds like a heavy machine gun, however here your console is screaming. I think that happens because when a device crashes it usually stops EVERYTHING including the sound processor and so it gets stuck on the last sound it played. As for minecraft, yeah, it does indeed seem like the disc reader died. Oh well.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the inserter is hot, you should probably leave it for 5 - 15 minutes.

According to [It Still Works:](https://itstillworks.com/unfreeze-xbox-360-19737.html)

> Screen freezes can occur on the Xbox 360 for several reasons. The mostly likely reasons include problems with a game disc, corrupted installed game files, network issues and lack of airflow to the console. ... To unfreeze your Xbox 360 and help prevent future freezes, do some troubleshooting to find out the cause.

The Xbox 360's screeching sound is probably from the disc you are playing on. If the disc is old, it won't read the disc. Here is some information from [Digital Innovations](https://www.digitalinnovations.com/why-wont-my-xbox-360-read-game-discs/) on how it might not read the disc:

> The major contributing factor to a disc read error is a dirty optical lens (the one that your Xbox 360 laser passes through to read the disc itself). If there is dirt or dust on the laser lens, your system will eventually fail to read the game disc.

The sudden screeching must be depending on the time on how much days/hours/months in total you played Fable 3. If it is new, it is probably your old 360 itself, but you really don't need a new one, you just need to take it for repair. Look [here](https://forum.digitpress.com/forum/showthread.php?111577-360-making-screeching-noise) for a reason on why it may be screeching. If the repair isn't affectable for a few minutes. You may need a new Xbox.